# Running an R script that involves Packages from Python Code

Tags: python, r, package

So I'm currently working on a simple python code to run a simple R script. The R script is only about 6 lines but uses the package "pracma". Using the subprocesses module in python, It runs the script but with the typical "Error in library(pracma) : there is no package called 'pracma' ". I am just looking for a simple solution to be able to run R scripts that have non-base packages installed. I know you can somehow do this using rpy2, but I cannot get that to install using pip, and I'm also using Anaconda3.

All in all, I'd just like a simple package that runs R scripts that have packages installed in them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the relevant piece of my Python code:

```
sp.run('Rscript Hausdorff.R', shell=True)

bFile = open("HausdorffData/hausdorff.txt", "r")
result = bFile.read()
bFile.close()
hausdorff_dist = float(result)

return hausdorff_dist
```

This is my R script:

```
library(pracma)

setwd('HausdorffData')

PointsA <- as.matrix(read.table("HFileA.txt", header = FALSE))
PointsB <- as.matrix(read.table("HFileB.txt", header = FALSE))

H = hausdorff_dist(PointsA, PointsB)
write(H, file = "hausdorff.txt",ncolumns = 1, append = FALSE)
```

This produces the following error:

```
Error in library(pracma) : there is no package called 'pracma'
Execution halted
```

Comment: Asking for a package, library or plugin here is not a good fit. Answers and comments tned to be opinion based (mainly). If you provide some code, we may help you providing working addition lines or corrections to your tried ones. Please try to show us your attempt. Thanks.

Comment: I edited to add some relevant code of what I'm referring to. Thanks @Dilettant

Comment: Looks like `Rscript` looks in wrong places? Did you try `.libPaths()` or the like?

Comment: Oh my lord thank you! I added in .libPaths(<directory-to-pracma>) and it seems to work. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. Please add as Update to question, or create an answer from it and accept it, so people "finding" this page, know what to do when they are stuck like you were. ;-) Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dilettant for this:

Even when R can seemingly run the script individually without this, when running the R script from something like python, we need to make sure the script knows what path our library is in. This is achieved by adding this line to the start of the code:

```
 .libPaths(dir\to\package)
```

If the code has any other lines involving changing working directory, those are unaffected by changing the library path.

Comment: This is a special use case. One does not need to specify `.libPaths()` when calling R scripts from other programs. I have run many R scripts from Python. How are you calling the R script? What is `sp.run()` which not from the subprocess module.

Comment: sp.run() is in the subprocesses module. It was added in python 3.5. And maybe it is indeed a special case, but no matter if i call it with sp.call() or sp.run(), I get the same error. This might be why I had such trouble finding a solution after tons of looking around when it was such an easy fix.